# update Label with Textfield inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a CollectionView inside my normal ViewController and if I select a cell and enter something in my textField and press the save Button it should update the nameLabel but I don't know how I can do that. Does anybody have a solution for this?

This is my current code:

```
    private let reuseIdentifier: String = "Item"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ItemCollection.delegate = self
    }



    func textEnter() {
        var text = textField.text

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath()
        let cell = ItemCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = text

    }

    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject, cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        textEnter()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ItemCollection: UICollectionView!


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/256, green: 128/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test1"
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

My Cell:

```
class ItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: where do button and text field located...

Comment: Both are in the ViewController

Comment: ofcourse...i am asking they are not in cell??right

Comment: last question: first entering text in textfield and then selecting cell, is fine........

Comment: No sadly not. Normally as soon the cell is tapped a containerView is opening where I configure the cell. I just cut it out so it's less code and easier to read and understand.

Comment: You can make your view controller the delegate for the text field and listen for when text is entered. When text is entered, you will then have to grab a reference to the cell you want and update its nameLbl. I don't know how you are planning on doing that, so I have not provided a code answer.

Comment: @keithbhunter Ok I did it like this but it crashes with this code: request for number of items before section 9223372036854775807 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view. And I updated my post with the new code.

Comment: a snapshot of you view can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you'll need to do to make this work.

First, you need to preserve context of the clicked cell by storing a "reference" to it. The easiest thing would be to introduce three new variables - section and item. Using these values you'll be able to re-create index path object and reference the cell.

Second, instead of calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(), you should construct the new Index Path object using the values saved in the previous step and call cellForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath). This may return a nil if the cell is not in view.

Note: this will set the label only when the user taps Save and the text will most likely be lost if the cell scrolls out of view and then back. In order to preserve this, you should store the entered value in a variable (or refer to the textbox directly) when creating the cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

Modified code example (some of the syntax may be off, I'm doing this from memory):

```
private let reuseIdentifier: String = "Item"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ItemCollection.delegate = self
    }

    // Store the clicked item location
    private section: Int = 0
    private item: Int = 0

    func textEnter() {
        var text = textField.text

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item inSection:section)
        let cell = ItemCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ItemCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = text
    }

    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject, cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
        textEnter()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ItemCollection: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/256, green: 128/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test1"
        return cell
    }

    // Need to capture the tapped cell in here
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        section = indexPath.section
        item = indexPath.item
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but I'm still kind of new to swift how exactly would that look like in code? Thanks!

Comment: Just updated with the modified version of your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there is an error in the didSelect method: Objective-C method 'collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:' provided by method 'collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)' in protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegate'

Comment: -> Bool was left over from copy-pasting. Try removing it.

Comment: Damnit it's always the small things. But anyway thank you very much for your help!